# Woo Commerce drop down default text after load?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I was curious how can I set the default text of what shows in the WooCommerce drop down after a page is selected. The drop down usually shows the category name, but  i would like for it to always show "Select your Category."

```
 <?php the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories', 'title=&hierarchical=1&orderby=name&dropdown=1' ); ?><br />
```